# Minimax algorithm with very large number of nodes and low depth

Tags: optimization, algorithms, game-theory, computational-mathematics, algorithmic-game-theory

I have a minimax tree as follows:

[image]

The number of branches can get extremely large (C(k,n)*C(n,j) to be specific), even though the depth is constant and very low. Is there any way to tackle this problem intelligently rather than going over each possible node? I can generate the value of each possible node but even generating that value might consume some time. Hence I am looking for a intelligent strategy that allows me to find the optimal solution very quickly.

I checked alpha-beta pruning, but it seems to be useful when the depth is higher and seems to have no impact when depth is very low yet the number of branches is very high.

**Additional question 1:** Is there an appropriate heuristic to this problem?

**Additional question 2:** Can applying alpha-beta pruning useful when we have to generate each node value as we go on? In my case, the computational problem is to generate all node values. Hence, I generate node values as I go on. But in alpha-beta pruning, it seems that all the node values are known a priori. Do you think is there a way to apply it to my case as well?

P.S: Sorry for the terrible paint representation, it's the best I can do in short time.

Comment: What values do k, n, and j have? What exactly is the depth? What do you mean that you can generate the value of each possible node? What do you seek: a Nash equilibrium policy for the game? A subgame perfect Nash equilibrium policy for the game (i.e. the optimal policy at each state)?

Comment: Hey, I'll try to explain but I am not very familiar with all the concepts in game theory. So if you need further clarification please ask. k, n, and j varies but let's say k=40, n=10, and j=5. The game tree is exactly as given in the image, so depth is equal to 2 I guess (There are more branches as I explained but there is no more subnodes). On a second thought, I think saying that "generating the value of each possible node" is not really correct, so I removed it. I am seeking for a Nash equilibrium policy for the game (The same as maximin here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ-mYn9fPag)

Comment: If there are no constraints on the leaf values, then in the worst case you'll have to traverse every node of the tree. But practically, yes you can do alpha-beta pruning: you can prune off an entire subtree once you've found that the min value for that subtree is already less than for some subtree you've already encountered. Also if there's any kind of structure to the values you might be able to solve it faster.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I can generate constraints on the leaf values, but for each node, range of these constraints would be really large. For instance, let's say for the first node the minimum value could take a value between 90 and 580; for the second, 100 and 440; for the third, 85 and 650. And the optimal value could be around 350. Hence I believe these constraints would not be very helpful.  To apply the alpha-beta pruning I think I need a heuristic, but I do not know any useful heuristic for the maximin algorithm. Finally, what kind of structure I should look for, could you elaborate that?

Comment: By "no constraints" i just mean that if the values can take on arbitrary values then you will need to traverse every node of the tree in the worst case. Conversely, by "any kind of structure", I just mean that depending on the specific problem, an efficient solution could exist. For alpha-beta pruning (i guess just alpha pruning in this case), you don't need a heuristic, it just means that you can prune traversal for an entire player 1 action as soon as you encounter a player 2 action which makes that p1 action worse than the best p1 action so far.